# AWS Sagermaker ClientError: Data download failed:PermanentRedirect (301)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

ClientError: Data download failed:PermanentRedirect (301): The bucket is in this region: us-west-1. Please use this region to retry the request

Answer (score 1):

Found it on my own. 
The S3 bucket I am using is in a different location. Used a different s# bucket. Everything works well now.